EmbeddedKafka produce value as topic
Maybe you can help me and tell me what I missed in setting up EmbeddedKafka
So I use EmbeddedKafka  to test my @KafkaListener in project:

I created simple test

@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(/*partitions = 1, ??? */ topics = {"topic-1", "topic-2"})
public class KafkaTest {...}


Then I initialize Producer<String, KafkaDto>

...
  private final EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;
  private Producer<String, KafkaDto> producer;

  public void prepare() {
    var props = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafkaBroker);
    var cf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props, new StringSerializer(), kafkaDtoSerializer);
    producer = cf.createProducer();
  }
...


Then in my test send test message to KafkaListener. So far everything seems to be working and there are no problems.

    var kafkaDto = ...;
    return new ProducerRecord<>(kafkaConsumerProperties.getTopic(), "", kafkaDto);


A message comes to my

  @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}'}",
                 groupId = "#{'${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}'}",
                 containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void message(@Payload KafkaDto message) {...}


And this is where the problem arises with the KafkaDto deserializer.

KafkaConfig
  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, KafkaDto> consumerFactoryDebezium(KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);     properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,KafkaDtoDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerProperties.getGroupId());
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerProperties.isEnableAutoCommit());

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties, new StringDeserializer(),
        new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(kafkaDtoDeserializer));
  }

KafkaDtoDeserializer
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaDtoDeserializer implements Deserializer<KafkaDto> {

  private final ObjectMapper mapper;

  @Override
  public KafkaDto deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {}
}

For some reason, byte[] data contains the same value as String topic ("topic-1" in byte). Instead of a serialized KafkaDto value.
I tried running the application and connecting to real Kafka. The listener works fine.
For some reason, the issue is with EmbeddedKafka.
Tell me what did I miss?

You need to be sure that your kafkaDtoSerializer works properly. See if you can debug its logic to determine where is the flaw.

Thanks @artem-bilan
You were right, I serialized topic instead of data
   @Override
   public byte[] serialize(String topic, KafkaDto data) {
     try {
       return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(topic); <- My mistake
...


